# Using the URL as a pseudo GET variable?

Tags: php

I understand how to parse the URL to get data.  What I don't know how to do, or rather, can't seem to search properly for it, is how to prevent redundant file creation.

Here's what I mean.  Let's say we have referrer1, referrer2, and referrer3.  I want the URL link for each referrer (they are each given their own) to be www.test.com/referrer1, www.test.com/referrer2, and www.test.com/referrer3.  Other than pulling the refferer name from the URL, the website functions identically.  Is there some way that I can do this that scales to having any arbitrary number of referrers, so that I don't have to make an identical subfolder for every single referrer?

Comment: How are you storing the data for said referrers?

Comment: In the database.  Website functionality is the exact same, the referrers stuff is just meant to be a bookkeeping thing for metrics.

Comment: So you'd say that `referrer1` is a user in the database or such?

Comment: I don't think your question matches your title. What is a `referer`? an html that calls the php script?

Comment: think of referrer as a get variable.  It has the same functionality. I basically want a "clean" looking data format that doesn't have get variables in the URL so a refferer can just say "go to www.test.com/myurl" instead of "go to www.test.com/index.php?referrer=myurl".  I know how to parse the URL for said information.  What I don't know is how do I set it up so that I won't have to mirror the site N times in N subfolders for N referrers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for url rewriting for example. You could have a adress example.com/index.php?ref=ref1,2,3 etc and use url rewrite to make it look lite example.com/referrer1,2,3 etc

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I was trying to search for!  Aren't things much easier when you finally find out what the word for it is :)  Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, i figured it was something like this you were looking for when you asked to drop the subfolder option.